# Scaling Time to Reconcile Genesis with Science

Tags: parashat-bereishit, science

Some scientists try to reconcile the biblical account of creation with the modern scientific view. see for example Gerald Shroeder's at http://www.aish.com/ci/sam/48951136.html

There he claims the sequence in the Biblical account matches the scientific account if we scale time (ex. light on day 1, sun on day 3...)

> The Bible goes out on a limb and tells you what happened on each of
>   those days. Now you can take cosmology, paleontology, archaeology, and
>   look at the history of the world, and see whether or not they match up
>   day-by-day.

however, it seems from the torah that the earth was created on the first day. (In the beginning God created heaven and earth..)

Anyone have any idea how they resolve this.

Comment: Where do you see in the torah that earth was created in one day? maybe you can bring a source to back up that claim? are there any proofs that say it explicity that it was one one day? In the begginning could be referring to a drawn out period of time.

Comment: In the beginning God created heaven and earth. plain meaning of eretz everywhere in the torah is the earth

Comment: where do you see it was one day?

Comment: plain meaning is gen.1:1-5 is day one

Comment: This is a general "how to understand Genesis Ch. 1" question, totally irrespective of Schroeder's time-scaling. Verse 1 says "and the earth", but later verses talk about the earth per se as on Day 3.

Comment: @Shalom seems correct. The question as you've worded it seems like a duplicate of [the linked-to question](q/30) -- but it doesn't seem to be worded so as to express the kernel of your intent. I'd edit it to something much simpler along the lines of "How can we reconcile God's creating Earth in Gen. 1:1 with His creating Earth on day 3?", but don't want to distort your intent, ray. If that is, in fact, your intent, though, then please make the edit.

Comment: @msh210 i hear what he's saying but the background that led to the question is also noteworthy i think

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a number of meforshim explain that it starts with the the general and then gets specific. Thus the first verse (Bereishis) refers to the entire process (all seven days).

The Art Scroll Chumash states

> "In the beginning of Hashem's Creating"
>
> This phrase is commonly rendered *In the beginning Hashem created*,
>   which would indicate that the Torah is giving the sequence of creation
>   ... *Rashi* and *Ibn Ezra* disagree, and our translation follows their
>   view.
>
> According to Ramban and most other commentators, however, the verse is
>   indeed chronologocal. It begins with a general statement *At the very
>   first moment Hashem created the heaven and Earth* ... The chapter
>   continues the day-today process ...

As an example, see Rav Hirsch on the first pasuk.

While it is too long to quote the entire commentary we see

> With this single verse, the principle and fundamental truth, the
>   principle and fundamental fact is reveled to us which completely
>   changes the point of view with which we regard the world and
>   ourselves. This single verse would have sufficed to teach us to think
>   of the world, as Hashem's world, and ourselves as creatures of Hashem,
>   ... But the Torah is not satisfied just to announce the creation of
>   the world by Hashem in general, by this one vers of creation. ... That
>   is why the Torah leads us up to all the individual phenomena of this
>   earthly diversity ...

1. In the beginning Hashem created the universe (shamayim va-aretz) (Pasuk 1

Pasuk 2 specifies the initial setup of "this earth" as confused and tangled (translation of Rav Hirsch)

2. There were seven stages to the creation (six "days" and Shabbos)
3. At the end of creation, human beings were created (details of how Adam and Chava were created).
4. Details of the beginning of the "life" of Adam and the first chet. Note that this was also before Shabbat so that it was still part of "creation".

Comment: Can you quote these meforshim?

Comment: Similarly the Ramban says first the elements were created that would be the building blocks for everything else.

Comment: @sabbahillel you write a number of meforshim, but you only reference Rav Hirsch. Can you back up your assertion? Or maybe edit the answer to be only featuring Rav Hirschs opinion.

Comment: rashi says it is not chronological. "it should have said brishona.."

Comment: if i understand correctly, you are saying the first verse refers to everything and then 2nd verse on it is details. correct? but then we have the same problem for on verse 2 the earth (aretz) is mentioned along with the water.

Comment: @ray That is why I added the Art Scroll commentary and the way it describes what Rashi saya. I also added the explicit second verse.

Comment: so you are saying " it starts with the the general and then gets specific" is going only according to the view that it is not chronological?

Comment: @ray Even according to the view that it is chronological, you can see that it starts with the general and then continues with the details.

Comment: but in verse 2 it already seems to start with the details. and chronologically the earth and water were not first. i.e. from a scientific perspective for whatever thats worth

Comment: Verse 1 is the general universe as a whole (shamayim va'aretz) verse 2 is the more detailed (aretz - sohu va'vohu) but is the general statement of what aretz started as, verse 3 etc are details of creation within the aretz.